# Adding a count column in SQL Server for groups of records

Tags: sql-server, increment

I am trying to update an existing table with an individual count of the record on each row in a count column.

The table has the following columns that need to be incremented:

```
MBR_NO, CLAIM_N0, Effective_Dt, incr_count
```

So a sample might look like this before the run:

```
MBR_NO | CLAIM_N0 | Effective_Dt   | incr_count |
-------+----------+----------------+------------+
1      | 2        | 1/1/2015       | NULL       |
1      | 4        | 5/5/2015       | NULL       |
1      | 5        | 6/7/2016       | NULL       |
1      | 7        | 8/7/2016       | NULL       |
2      | 2        | 4/3/2015       | NULL       |
2      | 5        | 5/21/2015      | NULL       |
3      | 8        | 3/27/2015      | NULL       |
```

I want to count by MBR_NO and update the Incr_count to look like this:

```
MBR_NO | CLAIM_N0 | Effective_Dt   | incr_count |
-------+----------+----------------+------------+
1      | 2        | 1/1/2015       | 1          |
1      | 4        | 5/5/2015       | 2          |
1      | 5        | 6/7/2016       | 3          |
1      | 7        | 8/7/2016       | 4          |
2      | 2        | 4/3/2015       | 1          |
2      | 5        | 5/21/2015      | 2          |
3      | 8        | 3/27/2015      | 1          |
```

I need to change that filed for processing later on.

I know this is not that complex but It seemed that the other topics offered solutions that don't incrementally update. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please consider formatting when asking question.  IT is really hard to read your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do this in a query with

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MBR_NO ORDER BY Effective_DT).`

but does it matter if the number changes?  i.e. in your example if you had

```
MBR_NO     EffectiveDate   RowNumber
------------------------------------
2             1/1/2017        1
2             5/1/2017        2
```

but if you inserted a row with an effective date of say 3/1/2017 it would change the row number for the 5/1/2017 row i.e.

```
MBR_NO     EffectiveDate   RowNumber
------------------------------------
2             1/1/2017        1
2             3/1/2017        2
2             5/1/2017        3
```

Comment: Yes I want the number to change essentially I am trying to count the number of member records and Use that in a loop processing elsewhere ,

Comment: ok well that works then. I would probably say just add that to a view unless you HAVE to have it in a table in which case a trigger might be best to update just those rows associated with that MBR_NO.

Answer (score 1):

You can query as below:

```
Select MBR_NO, CLAIM_N0, Effective_Dt,
   incr_count = count(MBR_NO) over(Partition by MBR_NO order by Effective_Dt)
from yourtable
```

Output as below:

```
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+
| MBR_NO | CLAIM_N0 | Effective_Dt | incr_count |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+
|      1 |        2 | 2015-01-01   |          1 |
|      1 |        4 | 2015-05-05   |          2 |
|      1 |        5 | 2016-06-07   |          3 |
|      1 |        7 | 2016-08-07   |          4 |
|      2 |        2 | 2015-04-03   |          1 |
|      2 |        5 | 2015-05-21   |          2 |
|      3 |        8 | 2015-03-27   |          1 |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: this needs sorting... is it possible to do so w/o sorting?

Comment: We need to provide incremental count based on atleast one order here the requirement seems to be on Effective_Dt... this can be any order based or requirement but it must have atleast on sort column to generate appropriate output